# Android: draw in screen percentage?

Tags: android, size, screen, surfaceview

How do I draw like a rectangle on a SurfaceView that has a width of 20% of the screen?

This is what I tried:

```
c.drawRect(0, 0, 20*proc, 20*proc, blackColor);
```

..where:

`proc` is a float of 1/100 of the screen width in pixels. (`getWidth()/100` on an extended SurfaceView)

`20` is the desired percentage.

This is the result on an AVD in eclipse:

**5x5 grid of rectangles, each has a width of 20% of the screen width:**
http://prntscr.com/4v2ti1

Shouldn't this work or what is wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: make float proc = getWidth()/100f;

Comment: Still not working :/ Thanks anyways..

Comment: What does getWidth() return?  What value does `proc` hold?  What is the actual width of the screen in pixels?

Comment: getWidth() is a method for the SurfaceView and returns its width in pixels.
proc=getWidth()/100;

My SurfaceView has a size of fill_parent on width and height, so its the same size as the screen

Comment: post the whole drawing code

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ei677uv22poie7y/GameCanvas.java?dl=0

(I dont know how to use github) xD